# How to cast object to generic type?

Tags: c#, .net, structuremap

I have many classes that implements **IBuilder<>** interface such the ones below

**UPDATED:**
each Model1, Model2... inherits from IModel

```
public class A : IBuilder<Model1>
{
     public Model1 Create(string param)
     {
         return new Model1();
     }
}
public class B : IBuilder<Model2>
{
     public Model2 Create(string param)
     {
          return new Model2();
     }
}
```

I'm using StructureMap to register all classes that inherit **IBuilder<>**

```
Scan(x =>
{
       x.TheCallingAssembly();
       x.AddAllTypesOf(typeof(IViewModelBuilder<>));                
});
```

**UPDATED**

Now, every time I need to get model of some Module I call **Do** function

```
public IModel Do(Module module)
{
        //ModelSettings is taken from web.config  
        var builderType = Type.GetType(string.Format("{0}.{1}ModelBuilder,{2}", ModelSettings.Namespace, module.CodeName, ModelSettings.Assembly));
        var builder = ObjectFactory.GetInstance(t) as IViewModelBuilder<>;

        return builder.Create("");            
}
```

I get compilation error in the line `ObjectFactory.GetInstance(t) as IViewModelBuilder<>`.
Many posts suggest to create **NOT** generic interface(IViewModelBuilder) and let the generic one to inherit it. And then I could make the casting like

```
ObjectFactory.GetInstance(t) as IViewModelBuilder
```

Is this the only way?

Thank you

Comment: You have a very confusing mix of real code an example code. How does IViewModelBuilder relate to IBuilder, would class A actually end with ModelBuilder in its name?, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't you make `Do()` generic?

```
var m = Do<B>();

public T Do<T>()
{ 
   var builder = (IViewModelBuilder<T>)ObjectFactory.GetInstance(typeof(T));
   return builder.Create("");
}
```

If you can't, using non-generic interface is probably your best bet, but there are other options like using reflection or C# 4's `dynamic`:

```
var m = Do(typeof(B));

public object Do(Type t)
{ 
   dynamic builder = ObjectFactory.GetInstance(t);
   return builder.Create("");
}
```

Comment: I can't make **Do** generic because I create the types, that Do will receive, at runtime. Is dynamic practical or it be better to rewrite my code? I just don't get it how to rewrite if I get types at runtime

Comment: It seems to me that there is no need for generics in your code at all. Just use non-generic `IViewModelBuilder`, that returns `IModel`.

Answer (score 5):

Your code for `Do` and `GetInstance` should be generic too. Basicly it could look something like this

```
public T Do<T> ()
{
     return ObjectFactory.GetInstance<T>().Create();
}
```

Comment: I can't make **Do** generic because I create the types, that Do will receive, at runtime

Comment: I've updated my post and I added the real code I use. I'll be glad if you could take a look

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is that you make an interface or a base class that your viewmodel inherit from. I.e:

```
public class Model1 : ModelBase
{
}

public class ModelBase
{
}

public ModelBase Do(Type t)
{
    var builder = ObjectFactory.GetInstance(t);
    return t.GetMethod("Create").Invoke(builder, new object[] { "" }) as ModelBase;
}
```

Comment: @Torbjon, I'm already using some kind of ModelBase. I updated my post if it could help.  I wanted to avoid using `Invoke`, because if I'll change `Create` to `Create2` I would forget to change it in `GetMethod`, but using real interface I'll get compilation error if I'll change method's name

Answer (score 1):

You need to introduce a non-generic `IViewModelBuilder` interface if you want to call it in a non-generic scenario. The generic `IViewModelBuilder<T>` would implement `IViewModelBuilder`.

The only other alternative is to invoke the create method via reflection, but I don't see why that would be preferred:

```
var builder = ObjectFactory.GetInstance(builderType);
var method = builderType.GetMethod("Create");
return (IModel) method.Invoke(builder, new[]{""});
```